# Merge two XML files, files having one to many relationship C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have two XML files,
 1. Contracts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
   <Contract>
      <ContractNo>1</ContractNo>
   </Contract>
   <Contract>
      <ContractNo>2</ContractNo>
   </Contract>
</File>
```

2. Asset

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
   <Asset>
      <ContractNo>1</ContractNo>
      <SomeData>XXXX</SomeData>
      <SomeData2>XXXX</SomeData2>
   </Asset>
   <Asset>
      <ContractNo>1</ContractNo>
      <SomeData>YYYY</SomeData>
      <SomeData2>YYYY</SomeData2>
   </Asset>
   <Asset>
      <ContractNo>2</ContractNo>
      <SomeData>ZZZZ</SomeData>
      <SomeData>ZZZZ</SomeData>
   </Asset>
</File>
```

A contract may have one or more assets. XML files are mapped by the contract number. I'm going to merge these two files and 
create the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
   <Contract>
      <ContractNo>1</ContractNo>
      <Asset>
         <SomeData>XXXX</SomeData>
         <SomeData2>XXXX</SomeData2>
      </Asset>
      <Asset>
         <SomeData>YYYY</SomeData>
         <SomeData2>YYYY</SomeData2>
      </Asset>
   </Contract>
   <Contract>
      <ContractNo>2</ContractNo>
      <Asset>
         <SomeData>ZZZZ</SomeData>
         <SomeData2>ZZZZ</SomeData2>
      </Asset>
   </Contract>
</File>
```

My approach is to iterate each contract of contract xml and find the contract number, then iterate assets xml and find the asset nodes of the above contract and
merge them to the contract xml

```
XmlNodeList contractsNodeList = contractsDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Contract");
string contractNumber;
foreach (XmlNode contractNode in contractsNodeList)
{
    //get the contract number
    contractNumber = contractNode.SelectSingleNode("ContractNo").InnerText;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contractNumber))
    {
        XmlNodeList assetsNodeList = assetsDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Asset");
        foreach (XmlNode assetNode in assetsNodeList)
        {
            //checking whether the current asset node has the current contract number 
            if (assetNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerText == contractNumber)
            {
                //remove the contract number of the asset node
                assetNode.RemoveChild(assetNode.ChildNodes[0]);
                //append the asset element to the contract xml
                contractNode.AppendChild(contractNode.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(assetNode, true));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works and generates the required xml. But it not much efficient. I don't have much experiance in working with XML. Please let me know any other ways to 
do this. Thank you!

Comment: Its a good system, why do you think its not efficient?

Comment: It is looking good and If you want to do it another way u can use `XDocument` and `Lambda expressions or LINQ`

Comment: @Amorphis I'm merging large xml files(around 15MB or more) and it takes some time to complete the merge process. I would like to know if there are any better ways to do this.

Comment: @IsuruSiriwardana Working with large files are always slow (although 15mb isn't large IMO), what you are doing i think is the fastest way because you are directly searching for what you need, you can also deserialize both XML's into objects and do the merge with C# classes and when you finish serialize it to a new file , this approach might be easier to understand and architecturally better, but it wont be faster.

Comment: Wouldn't it suit better for codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally read in the assets, populating an `ILookup<int, XElement>` and removing the `ContractNo` element afterwards (as it's just slightly simpler in LINQ to XML). Then read the contracts, populating the assets from the dictionary. Something like:

```
XDocument assets = XDocument.Load("assets.xml");
var lookup = assets.Root.Elements("Asset")
                        .ToLookup(x => (int) x.Element("ContractNo"));
assets.Root.Elements("Asset").Elements("ContractNo").Remove();

XDocument contracts = XDocument.Load("contracts.xml");
foreach (var contract in contracts.Root.Elements("Contract").ToList())
{
    var id = (int) contract.Element("ContractNo");
    contract.Add(lookup[id]);
}
contracts.Save("results.xml");
```

Note that this doesn't detect contracts that don't have any assets - they'll just be left as they are.

All of this is doable in the "old" `XmlDocument` API, but LINQ to XML does tend to make it much simpler.